# Eventbrite - reuse QR code for different events

Tags: qr-code, eventbrite

I want to have a personal QR code assigned for each guest. 
This QR will be used for the registration for the first event. 
 1. Can I asign a persona QR for certain guest?
 2. Can I reuse this QR in another event another date?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eventbrite to sign people in, e.g. by scanning the QR code in the Organizer app, then you will not be able to do what you propose. The reason is that barcodes are uniquely created for each registered attendee to each event, and you cannot control or modify them. The QR code is just a representation of that barcode number.

However, if you want to manage attendees using some other system, you could create arbitrary QR codes for each attendee by some other identifier and then use this to look them up in your own database, which could be populated with attendee data via the Eventbrite API and perhaps webhooks.